# logically, Is it allow to repeat "else" more than one time in the if statment?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

While i'm learning basics of CS. i saw a if statment not use "else" more than one time in every if statment!
when he have 3 options he write: `if () {} else { if () {} else {} }`!

why don't we write: `if () {} else {} else {}`?!

Comment: How would the engine know which `else` to follow?

Comment: I think you want `else if`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's a syntax error and secondly if you just have two elses anyway which you both want executing, you could just put them together.

Comment: syntax not error.. look her: http://www.clipular.com/c/4992433807949824.png?k=MkbV07yg_zgeLFEQsChoRhWl4XQ

Comment: That's not the same thing, there's always an if and then an else not else else.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript language supports the following conditional constructs.

[`if`, `else if`, `else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

```
var myName = "Darren";

if (myName === "Darren") {
   alert("My name is Darren");
}
else if (myName === "user3860868") {
   alert("My name is user3860868");
}
else {
   alert("My name is not Darren or user3860868");
}
```

The first statement checks if the `myName` variable is Darren, if it matches an alert box is shown with my name, if it does not, it then checks if the `myName` variable is equal to user3860868, if the name does not match again it finally falls into the else statement and displays the last alert box.

You can have multiple `else if` statements but only one `else` statement.

Comment: This is nice way.. Thank you.. but look at that way: http://www.clipular.com/c/4992433807949824.png?k=MkbV07yg_zgeLFEQsChoRhWl4XQ